# To get content with whateverorigin.org from other domain

Tags: javascript, json, same-origin-policy

Is it possible by this request to get specify content part by class or id. This code is:

```
$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
          encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?',
          function(data){
            $("#content").html(data.contents);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and this is how i did it.

i needed to get the whois information about certain sites and display it onto my website.

for eg i needed the whois info of http://megaanswers.com/, which is available at www.domaininformation.de/whois/megaanswers.com, so with whateverorigin.org i got the jsonp request as below http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domaininformation.de%2Fwhois%2Fmegaanswers.com (after encodeURIComponent) but this contains the whole page, but i just needed the part of the page within class="result" .

Now data.contents would give the html code of the whole page. Now the element with class result is selected using jquery and its html is appended to the div with id="target"

This is how the final code would look like

```
<div id="target"></div> 
<script>            
                $.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8", //maybe "ISO-8859-1"
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"});

    $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
    encodeURIComponent('http://www.domaininformation.de/whois/megaanswers.com') + '&callback=?',
    function(data) {
       var thecontents = data.contents;
       var required = $('.result', thecontents).html(); // select '.result' class in 'thecontents'
       $('#target').html("<pre>" + required + "</pre>");
    });

</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because of the same-origin policy,

> all modern web browsers impose a security restriction on network connections

You can try to use a proxy, check out this documentention http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Comment: yes, they can, The OP is using whateverorigin.org ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of solutions and also couple of barriers in your way to achieve what you want. the main barrier is `Access-Origin` security restriction.

1. First solution is to use or create a server-side API, which could be a Java servlet, C# Handler or just a PHP file in your server. This could be useful if you don't have access to the the other server to modify its headers and add the `Access-Origin` header. this API would serve as a proxy. In this solution you can be more specific in you API and use some parameters to load just a specific part of the other url's content, whether it is has a html or JSON content.
2. The other way is to add the the `Access-Origin` header to the server and allow some specific urls to have access to that url's content without facing with security restriction, which needs you to have access to the server. Then if you want to filter the content you should do it using JavaScript.
3. The other way if you have access to the server is to add `JSONP` support to the server, which basically is the way we usually get around the `Access-Origin` security restriction.

Comment: my request works but show whole site.. without images but I need to parse content by different classes

Comment: @Julia: the reason why it happens is it loads the html with all the relative image paths, for instance if you load google page this way the logo's src attribute would be `'/images/srpr/logo11w.png'` and if you want it show you the google logo image, you should parse your image manually and change it to `'https://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo11w.png'`.